# Safe place to cross border from Mexico into U.S.?

Tags: usa, safety, borders, mexico

I'm currently in Mexico (Quintana Roo state) and need to enter the U.S. through a land border crossing. My plan is to fly to an airport near the border, take a cab to the crossing, and then walk into the U.S.

From Cancun airport there are direct flights to Reynosa, Ciudad Juarez, and Tijuana. The [U.S. State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/mexico-travel-advisory.html) says "Do Not Travel" to Tamaulipas state, where Reynosa is located. Tijuana and Ciudad Juarez seem to have some of the highest [murder rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_murder_rate) in the world.

Would it be safe to go through any of these three? I'd take a cab from the airport directly to the crossing.

**EDIT** I have lost my passport, so it seems that the CBX bridge from Tijuana airport is unfortunately not an option.

**EDIT 2** I'm not a U.S. citizen but have a green card as well as a U.S. drivers license, which I'm both carrying with me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99121/discussion-on-question-by-maxim-safe-place-to-cross-border-from-mexico-into-u-s).

Answer (score 18):

For $30, you can walk directly from the Tijuana baggage claim to the United States border via [CBX (Cross Border Xpress)](https://www.crossborderxpress.com/en/).  That seems like the safest option, even if the others are not very dangerous.

It does require a passport, however, so if your need to use the land border is motivated by a lack of a passport, it looks like this won't help you.  Their *Requirements* page notes that

> It is mandatory to have your official travel documents to access the bridge and these may be requested by CBX staff.

In a comment, you said:

> Yes, I lost my passport, so the CBX bridge is unfortunately not an option. Should have mentioned this in the question (will update).

As you do not have your passport you might consider going to the [US consulate in Cancun](https://mx.usembassy.gov/embassy-consulates/merida/consular-agencies/) to [get a new one](https://mx.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passport-services/how-passport/).  They can get you an [emergency](https://mx.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/passport-services/emergency-passport/) passport [in a matter of hours](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/emergencies/lost-stolen-passport-abroad.html) if need be.  Given Cancun's tourist industry, I can only imagine that this happens frequently and they can deal with it quite efficiently.

In an edit, you said

> I'm not a U.S. citizen but have a green card as well as a U.S. drivers license, which I'm both carrying with me.

Why didn't you say so in the first place?  You should be able to fly directly to the US with your green card.  Permanent residents do not need a passport to enter the US.  You should also be able to use CBX with only the green card.  The fact that the website doesn't mention this seems more likely to be a fault of the website than anything else, since it leaves several cases uncovered, including that of green card holders.

TIMATIC says:

> Passport Exemptions:
>   Passengers with a Permanent Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551).

Comment: Yes, I lost my passport, so the CBX bridge is unfortunately not an option. Should have mentioned this in the question (will update).

Comment: Is this an XY problem? What does "lost" mean? If you're a US citizen, could you not obtain an emergency travel document from the US embassy or consulate?

Comment: @Maxim if you have a few days, you might just want to replace your passport.  I've edited the answer with some relevant links.

Comment: Downvoter please explain.

Comment: Would CBX prevent one from seeing CBP if they don't have a passport?

Comment: @JonathanReez according to their website, yes.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: phoog, are you sure that, say you have >no< passport, and a green card .. is it possible to (a) board an international flight (well, from Mexico specifically) and (b) then enter the US?

Comment: @Fattie I'm not sure.  The airline is free to require more stringent documentation than the destination country.  But according to TIMATIC, it is allowed.  OP could probably save himself a lot of trouble by calling a few airlines.

Comment: @phoog - you've got the FACTS from timatic, so that's great

Comment: @phoog "The airline is free to require more stringent documentation than the destination country" isn't true. They're allowed/obliged to verify that the passenger meets the destination requirements, nothing more nothing less. That said, mistakes from handling staff are depressingly common, not least in North America regarding NEXUS card holders.

Comment: @Crazydre "nothing more, nothing less": that is incorrect. the airline has an interest in verifying the identity of the passenger presenting him or herself for transport.  Ryanair is often cited here as an airline that has documentation requirements more stringent than those required by law.

Comment: @phoog "Ryanair is often cited here as" Only for UK-Ireland travel, and that's because it's a special case with CTA regulations enabling passport-free travel for British/Irish citizens, whilst at the same time it technically needs to be known that the person is a British/Irish citizen. Ryanair thus requires a passport (or Irish passport card). Other than that, could you mention a single other Ryanair example, because I for one know of none.

Comment: @Crazydre they also require proof of immigration status for intra-Schengen flights, for no good reason as far as I can see.

Comment: @phoog People granted temporary statuses but not allowed to leave the relevant member state, or LTV visa holders, could face deportation from Europe in case of an internal spot check, and the airline would be fined in that case. The reason why so few other airlines do it is because such checks are rare (most common in France though). Also, which travel documents are accepted isn't quite uniform across Schengen. I was told by an internal Ryanair department that those are the reasons

Comment: @Crazydre do you have a link to any law that provides for such fines?  I've looked, but not found anything.  What differences exist in the acceptance of travel documents?

Comment: @phoog Most notably, there's no unified Schengen visa regime for non-ordinary (e.g. diplomatic) passports. FOr example Philippine diplomatic passport holders require a visa for e.g. FR/Benelux but not e.g. DE/Scandinavia. Also, for example the Australian Document of Identity is accepted for LV and a couple of others (don't remember), but not most. Monaco/San Marino ID cards aren't accepted for IS/SE - San Marino ones also not for CZ/HU/LV

Comment: @Crazydre yes, I am aware of that.  What I'd like to find, though, if it exists, is any Schengen country's law that provides for fining an airline for bringing someone without proper documents *from another Schengen country.*  I've seen similar laws for non-Schengen countries, and I'm sure that they exist for Schengen countries for non-Schengen passengers, but I wonder whether they're actually applicable to Schengen passengers.

Comment: @phoog For the purposes of entry requirements **other than** duration of stay, Schengen isn't treated as a single country, only in terms of *processing* entries/exits on an official basis (stamps...). The Schengen Borders code doesn't only concern the external border, also mentioning the internal border in several contexts. Where nothing is explicitly stated, a rule applies to both. I don't see anything about fines in the Schengen Borders code, but one can read about the carrier sending passengers back, which applies to both the internal and external border since nothing's explicitly stated.

Comment: @phoog Haven't found any law of individual member states; however I recently corresponded about this with the Swedish NOA (national operations department of the police), who are also TIMATIC's local sources btw, who told me that, should any internal checks at an airport take place, any non-compliant passenger would be sent back (or possibly deported from Europe if they've forfeited their status where they came from by leaving) and the airline fined

Answer (score 6):

I live in Tijuana, and cross the border at the two Tijuana ports of entry regularly without issue. If you stay away from the dodgy parts of the city (eg the red light district) and don't do anything stupid you'll be fine and safe.

People cross in the US without a passport regularly here - you'll be asked more questions and need to prove you're a US citizen (a birth certificate or driver license is usually enough).